# IOS 13 Blurry low resolution photos in gallery

Tags: photos.app, ios

Has anyone noticed that since upgrading to iOS 13 some photos are low resolution and blurry when viewing them? On my phone it seems to be about 50% of them.

If I click the edit button the images are clear and very sharp again.

Feels like it’s some sort of optimisation that’s buggy.

They are not stored on iCloud as I have 256gb iPhone XS and same happens offline.

I can’t see any settings for this. Any ideas or am I alone with this?

Thanks in Advance for any suggestions

Comment: I have 4 devices using iOS 13.1 and haven't seen blurry photos on any of them.  What do you mean by "They are not stored on iCloud as I have 256gb iPhone XS and same happens offline"?  If you have iCloud syncing your photos then all your photos are in iCloud.  Do you have `Optimize iPhone Storage` turned on for Photos?

Comment: I’m just aware that when the phone is low on storage the phone keeps a low resolution version locally and then loads the higher resolution version when viewing and it is not this behaviour that I am seeing. This is something else. I have a feeling it is related to images that have been cropped and filtered.

Comment: What about Optimize iPhone Storage setting?

Comment: As I said I’m aware of this behaviour and it’s not this (same thing happens offline so it can’t be getting a higher res version from iCloud)

Comment: @LennyD can you export some of such photos to some Mac and see the sizes? It happens on my phone for ~20 MB (DSLR) photos. I don't know what size iPhone XS clicks photos at.